# MigraDoc Absolute Position a Footer Text Frame to Bottom Page Edge

Tags: migradoc

I need to align my footer to the absolute bottom of each page and span across the whole page.

I have used a textframe as this can be absolute positioned, so will ignore my page margins and I can get it completely across the page but I cannot get it to sit right at the bottom.

I have tried :

```
  fr.Top =  *any number*; 
  fr.Top = ShapePosition.Bottom;
```

Neither of these cause it to move at all

```
 fr.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Page;
```

This makes it sit perfectly at the top, but I need it at the bottom

I think I need an offset on it but I don't know how to apply it as the top property does nothing for me.

My Page Set up is as follows:

```
        section.PageSetup.PageFormat = PageFormat.A4;
        section.PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = true;

        AddFooter(ref section);

        section.PageSetup.LeftMargin = "1 cm";
        section.PageSetup.TopMargin = "1 cm";
        section.PageSetup.RightMargin = "1 cm";
        section.PageSetup.BottomMargin = "1 cm";

        section.PageSetup.HeaderDistance = "1 cm";
        section.PageSetup.FooterDistance = "0 cm";
```

With Addfooter like this:

```
 public static void AddFooter(ref Section section)
    {
        Unit pageWidth = GetWidth(section);<- custom function

        TextFrame fr = new TextFrame();
        var footerTable = fr.AddTable();

      ~~footer table info here~~

        fr.Width = new Unit(pageWidth);
        fr.MarginLeft = new Unit(4);//set as 4 because for some reason it as
       sitting slightly to the left

         /**
      SET BOTTOM POSITION HERE
        **/

     fr.RelativeHorizontal = RelativeHorizontal.Page;//This makes it sit to the left of the page

        section.Footers.Primary.Add(fr.Clone());
        section.Footers.EvenPage.Add(fr.Clone());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not set the `Top` property of the `TextFrame`, set the `WrapFormat.DistanceTop` property instead. Also set the `WrapFormat.Style` property to `WrapStyle.Through`.
See also: https://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=6922#p6922

AFAIK you do not have to set the `MarginLeft` property of the frame if you set the `Rows.LeftIndent` property of the table to 0. By default tables have a negative indent so that text in tables is aligned with text outside tables.

Comment: setting   fr.WrapFormat.Style = WrapStyle.Through; makes it go to the bottom but some of my table goes off the page. the wrapformat.distance top doesn't seem to change anything.  How do I move it up a bit?